# Eventbrite iframe and Google Analytics - can't persist traffic source info

Tags: google-analytics, eventbrite

The Eventbrite embedded checkout widget that generates an iframe for event registration can be tracked with Google Analytics but it's not able to track how users get to the event page (traffic source missing). Every user gets a new clientId once they start interacting with the widget.

The "cross-domain" solution Eventbrite offers doesn't work for iframe: https://www.eventbrite.com/support/articles/en_US/Troubleshooting/how-to-enable-cross-domain-and-ecommerce-tracking-with-google-universal-analytics?lg=en_US

My website: https://courtneyscharff.github.io/
I'd like to keep users on this domain, instead of re-directing the users to an Eventbrite.com page.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to come up with a solution to whatever Eventbrite is currently doing for you yourself, so you can host it yourself.

Comment: You're right @Mast

Comment: @SetraYappi Did you come up with a solution? I am facing exactly the same issue! The doc is saying to pass the Google Analytics client id when creating the widget by passing the `googleAnalyticsClientId` to the parameter object. I am doing it and the iframe url is built with the `eboga` query param filled with it, but same as you, on Google Analytics, I see that traffic source is considered as `direct` instead of my website.